# Nonlinear differential equation $x\frac{dy}{dx}+\ln\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+\ln\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-y=0$$

My approach:

Take exponantial everything:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}=1$$

Observe that $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}=\frac{dy}{dx}e^{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}$$

so taking antiderivative $$e^{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}=x+\phi(y)$$

now $$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=\ln(x+\phi(y))$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y/x+\ln(x+\phi(y))/x$$

I dont know how to specify $\phi$ and solve this. How to solve this differential equation?

Comment: The solution is $y=x$.

Comment: Remember that $$x \frac{dy}{dx} - y = - \ln\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right).$$This will give you simpler expression $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x + \phi(y)}$$

Comment: Why didn't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ODE is called [Clairaut's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation). Write as $$y = x \frac{dy}{dx} + \ln\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$
then take the derivative of both side. Can you take it from here?

The solutions will be $$y = Cx + \ln C$$ for arbitrary positive constant $C$
and $$y = -1 - \ln(-x).$$